# Resizing font in textarea without increasing textarea size

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, textarea

I was messing around with some Jquery to have a slider control the size of font in a text area and used something like:

```
...  
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#t_area').css("font-size", ui.value + "px");
}
....
```

within the function to control the slider.  I noticed that even when I didn't have text in the textarea, it still increased in size when I moved the slider (and also grew too large when there was text in it.)  So I was wondering if there was a way to increase the size of the text without having that side effect?

Thanks

Comment: You could add an if statement checking if t_area contained data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set dimensions on the `textarea`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6qZAh/

```
textarea {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;    
}
```

Without explicit dimensions, the size is based on the rows/cols of the `textarea`. Even when not those values are not explicitly set, the user agent uses a default.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6qZAh/1/

```
$("textarea").on("click",function(){
   var t = $(this);
   alert(t.prop("rows"));
   alert(t.prop("cols"));
});
```

In Chrome and IE9, this shows me "2" and "20".

This appears to be [spec-driven](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-textarea-element) (emphasis mine):

**Rows**

> If applying the rules for parsing non-negative integers to the
>   attribute's value results in a number greater than zero, then the
>   element's character height is that value; otherwise, **it is 2.**

**Cols**

> If applying the rules
>   for parsing non-negative integers to the attribute's value results in
>   a number greater than zero, then the element's character width is that
>   value; otherwise, **it is 20.**

Answer (score 2):

css:

```
textarea { max-width:300px;max-height:300px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use css for this.

```
textarea{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if($('#t_area').text() != ""){    
  $('#t_area').css("font-size", ui.value + "px");
}
```

Comment: -1 - That's not necessary, nor would it fix the problem. The OP specifically states that this an issue even when there is *not* text in the `textarea`. If you amend your answer, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Yes thats because there was no condition whether it has text or not. My solution will increase the font-size only if the textarea has something otherwise it will take its default declared font-size. Also let Sam do the acceptance.

Comment: The OP says that it grows in both cases. Yours will only modify it in the case that it is empty. Your solution would also need to account for setting the size once text *was* added. There is a simpler solution (set explicit dimensions) that the other answers state.